# Is there a Swing implementation of a "rearrangable accordian" component? Or what is it called?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Basically there can be one or more of these controls with panels in them, and the panels can be dragged between them, or slide within the control to change positions, minimized, or closed.

[image]

Blue area can have scroll bars if shrunk too small.

Is there a name for this? And is there a Java swing implementation of it I can try?

EDIT: some examples of what I'm talking about.[image][image]

EDIT: found the term "accordion", updated title to better reflect question and still looking for correct name for what I'm describing, if there is one.

[image]

Comment: Looks kind of like JInternalFrames held by a JDesktopPane.

Comment: [How to Use Internal Frames](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I mean for them to be locked to the width of the vertical control they live in, unable to move left to right or hang off into nothingness, and can only slide and displace each other. Also these have "windowshading" collapse and are unable to overlap, as well as being compacted to the top of their column. Going to update the original post with some examples soon.

Comment: They are still `JInternalFrame`s in the concept of Swing.  You could utilise different layout managers or maybe a custom `DesktopManager` to implement your required functionality.  Otherwise, from Swing's perspective, nothing like that exists

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yeah, I figured it wasn't a standard control, but I've seen it often enough to hope it had a name. I'm looking for a library that implements it using swing, or the name of it so I can find one on my own. Failing that, I'll at least know what to call mine when I make it. I've enjoyed using it in the past and it seems to fit my application.  Also I have added those examples now.

Comment: As I said, you could fake it using `JInternalFrame`s and a custom Layout Manager and/or `DesktopManager`.  You could also have a look at the `JXCollapsiblePane` from [SwingLabs SwingX project](https://java.net/projects/swingx/downloads/directory/releases)

Comment: @MadProgrammer The stacked collapsible panes are called [accordions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accordion_%28GUI%29). A typical accordion isn't rearrangeable though, so I'm still looking around.

Answer (score 0):

The collapsible sub-panels, particularly in the blender example, fit the description of an [accordion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accordion_%28GUI%29) control. But most accordions can't have their panels re-arranged by dragging.